# How to attach properties to terms?

Tags: prolog

I want to attach properties to my terms, from a set of about 50 different properties. Usually only a small subset of them are used for a given term. There are many ways to represent these properties, but I am not satisfied with any of them.

For the sake of discussion, here is a set of properties and their possible values:

```
hair: bald, blonde, brune, red
eyes: blue, green, brown
first_name: John, Dick, Harry
```

There are many ways to represent these properties, for example with a list of pairs:

```
[eyes-blue, hair-blonde]
```

The only representation that seems to work is to use a very long list, where each index is used for a specific property:

```
?- T1=[blonde,_,_], T2=[_,blue,_], T1=T2.
T1 = T2, T2 = [blonde, blue, _1266]

?- T1=[X,_,_], X=blue.
T1 = [blue, _1230, _1236],
X = blue
```

But it's unreadable with 50 properties, and very bugprone (in my case, a whole set of predicates is dedicated to each property, and sometimes to each value of a property).

The way I would use such a feature would be by having conditions like "Terms T1 and T2 have the same value for property X", or "Terms T1 and T2 are the same", where T1 and T2 have attributes which can be set elsewhere, or can be left unset.

Using dicts desn't work, because unset keys are considered non-existent:

```
?- T1 = _{eyes:blue, hair:blonde}, T2 = _{eyes:blue}, T1 = T2.
false.
```

For this to work, I would need to initialize each term with the 50 (mostly irrelevant) properties with free variables, on the off-chance that some of them will be used.

What other options do I have? I am open to using a different logic programming language if there is something closer to my needs than prolog.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are describing by *`[hair-blonde]=[eyes-blue]` to be unified as `[hair-blonde, eyes-blue]`*. That's not what unification means. Are you really talking about maintaining collections of attributes, where a given collection of them are consistent with one another? My hunch is there's a simple representation using lists, and you'll need to write a predicate that does your "unification" operation (which I would not call "unification"). In Prolog *unification* of compound terms means that term-by-term and argument-by-argument they will unify.

Comment: Yes lurker, you understood it right. I used the word "unification" because SWI-Prolog documentation does mention that in the future, they may offer a unification of dicts that matches what I am looking for.

Comment: How about `T1 >:< T2`?

Comment: Prolog **unification** is a very fundamental concept and overloading its meaning for a data structure is just unfeasible. But nothing stops you from defining a comparison operator for your own Prolog data structure that does _exactly_ what you want.

Comment: Sorry for spamming with comments. Just to point out that dicts in SWI-Prolog are already an extension to Prolog: they are non-transparent terms, you can only access them through the API that is provided. Which means it is even more important that unification of dicts does the least surpising thing possible.

Answer (score 6):

With the "very long list", you have indeed found *one* possible representation that lets you directly use Prolog's built-in **unification** to perform the task for you.

As you note, this comes at a price though: It's unreadable, error-prone, wasteful etc.

There are many possible ways to solve the task, and I would like to give you two pointers that I hope you find relevant for your task.

## Option 1: Use lists of pairs

This is in fact already mentioned in your post. Pairs of the form `hair-blonde` etc. are a natural way to represent the available data. By convention, `(-)/2` is frequently used to denote *pairs* in Prolog.

All that is missing is precisely describing what "merging" such pairs means. You call it "unification", so let us use this terminology although it is of course different from **syntactic** unification that is available with `(=)/2`. One way to define the relation we want is:

```
unify_pairs([], APs, APs).
unify_pairs([A1-P1|APs1], APs2, APs) :-
        if_(selectd_t(A1-P1, APs2, APs2Rest),
            APs=[A1-P1|Rest],
            if_(attr_exists_t(A1, APs2),
                false,
                APs = [A1-P1|Rest])),
            unify_pairs(APs1, APs2Rest, Rest).

attr_exists_t(A, APs, T) :-
        pairs_keys(APs, As),
        memberd_t(A, As, T).

selectd_t(E, Xs0, Xs, T) :-
   i_selectd_t(Xs0, Xs, E, T).

i_selectd_t([], [], _, false).
i_selectd_t([X|Xs], Rest, E, T) :-
   if_(X=E, (T=true,Rest=Xs), (Rest = [X|Rs],i_selectd_t(Xs, Rs, E, T))).
```

This uses [**`library(reif)`**](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl) and two auxiliary predicates to distinguish the different cases.

Your test cases work as required. For example:

```
?- unify_pairs([hair-blonde], [eyes-blue], Ps).
Ps = [hair-blonde, eyes-blue].

?- unify_pairs([eyes-blue], [eyes-brown], Ps).
false.
```

Importantly, we can use it in *all directions*, and so we can also post significantly *more general* queries. For example:

```
?- unify_pairs([T1-P1], [T2-P2], TPs).
T1 = T2,
P1 = P2,
TPs = [T2-P2] ;
TPs = [T1-P1, T2-P2],
dif(T2, T1),
dif(f(T2, P2), f(T1, P1)).
```

Such answers help us to obtain a better understanding of the relation, and to test it more exhaustively.

## Option 2: Use lists of pairs again

The second pointer I would like to include is found in [**`library(ordsets)`**](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.3.2/html/sicstus/lib_002dordsets.html) and similar libraries that ship with several Prolog systems.

This *again* lets you use *lists*, even lists of *pairs*. Importantly, lists are available in *all* Prolog systems. Various operations are quite efficient due to the way these libraries represent *sets* as *ordered lists*.

However, the price you may pay in such cases is the *generality* explained in the first approach. I suggest you first try the more general approach (i.e., Option 1), and then, only if necessary, resort to lower-level approaches that are more error-prone and less general.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps a lot indeed.

Comment: Note that you can *easily* express other constraints in this "lists of pairs" representation. For example, to express that the attribute `A` has the same property in both lists `Ls1` and `Ls2`, you can use the **conjunction** of constraints: `member(A-P, Ls1), member(A-P, Ls2)`. The other relations you would like to express can also easily be expressed as predicates. For example, you can use `identical_attributes(APs1, APs2) :- ...` and define the conditions that make these pairs *identical* in your view.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe say "unification" but you mean something different from what *unification* normally means in Prolog which is why your question might be mistaken for a different question. You could do some things with SWI-Prolog dicts:

```
?- _{hair:blonde, eyes:blue} >:< _{eyes:blue}.
true.

?- _{hair:blonde, eyes:blue} >:< _{eyes:blue, hair:Color}.
Color = blonde.

?- _{hair:blonde, eyes:blue} >:< _{eyes:blue, hair:bald}.
false.
```

but you cannot directly do what you need, because if you "put" into a dict you **add or replace** which is not what you want.

```
?- R =_{eyes:blue}.put(_{hair:blonde}).
R = _7436{eyes:blue, hair:blonde}.
```

(this one was OK)

```
?- R =_{eyes:blue}.put(_{eyes:brown}).
R = _7436{eyes:brown}.
```

(this is not what you want, is it?)

what you want I don't know what to call in words but it is some form of finding union on keys in key-value pairs. But you can just do it with dicts I think if you first do `P1 >:< P2` and then `put_dict(P1, P2, Result)`?

```
?- P1 = _{eyes:blue},
   P2 = _{hair:blonde,eyes:brown},
   P1 >:< P2, put_dict(P1, P2, Result). 
false.

?- P1 = _{eyes:blue},
   P2 = _{hair:blonde},
   P1 >:< P2, put_dict(P1, P2, Result).
Result = _10044{eyes:blue, hair:blonde}.

?- P1 = _{eyes:blue},
   P2 = _{hair:blonde,eyes:blue},
   P1 >:< P2, put_dict(P1, P2, Result).
Result = _10046{eyes:blue, hair:blonde}.
```

Please respond if this is what you were asking because I am really not sure? But what is even more important actually is that you think a bit more carefully about the *real* problem you are trying to model because maybe? (just maybe?) you are thinking of it in terms of solution that is not as good as another solution that will make the problem be a lesser problem or a problem with already existing better solutions. Maybe it will help if you provide even more context about your problem in your question, because now there is enough context about how you tried to solve it but I don't know what you are really solving.

Comment: I realize I didn't tell anything about how I would use the feature, and it's definitely missing from my question. I want to be able to have a condition in a rule that says "Terms T1 and T2 have the same value for property X", or "Terms T1 and T2 are the same". So far, it seem that only the long list solution works for these conditions to work. Combining terms into an output term (either with dicts in your answer or unify_pairs in Mat's answer) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thank you very much. dicts seem to do more than I thought, but it's unclear to me how I would implements the conditions I mentioned in the previous comment. I updated my question to include examples of what I want to do.

Comment: @Jerome But what is the problem? My answer and now more answers show how you can do all these things, or maybe not?

Answer (score 1):

You could make the attributes one-arity terms, like this:

```
hair(bald)
hair(blonde)
eyes(blue)
eyes(green)
...
```

That would rule out unifications like

```
hair(blonde) = hair(red)
```

and you could quite easily write your own predicate for combining two lists, which could also block/filter out multiple instances of the same attribute.

In languages with strong typing this is a nice representation, but I'm not sure it's so useful in Prolog. Anyway it is a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I understand your question but I don't think I understand your difficulty. You could achieve what you want with dicts, with assocs, with lists of pairs.... You say:

> Terms T1 and T2 have the same value for property X

Here it is with dicts, like the [answer by @User9213](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44069693/1812457):

```
?- _{a:1, foo:2, bar:3}.a = _{a:2, foo:22, baz:33}.a.
false.

?- _{a:1, foo:2, bar:3}.a = _{a:1, foo:22, baz:33}.a.
true.
```

In other words, to compare a "property" of two dicts, you just say `Dict1.X = Dict2.X`. Note that this also works with `X` a variable:

```
?- X = a, _{a:1, b:2}.X = _{a:1, b:432432}.X.
X = a.
```

The same would work with any other option already mentioned: with `library(assoc)` (just get the values for that key and compare), or even for lists of pairs (just do `member(Key-Value, List)` and compare values).

Then, you also say,

> Terms T1 and T2 are the same

Now you really can just compare dicts. For assocs, I am not certain if two assocs are always the same if they have the same contents, but you can make lists and compare those. And if you keep your lists of pairs sorted on keys, you can just compare, as with dicts.

Finally, you say:

> where T1 and T2 have attributes which can be set elsewhere, or can be left unset.

This is ambiguous. If an attribute is unset, just leave it out of the dict/assoc/list. "Set elsewhere" I really don't get.

You need to write some code down and get a feel for how things could be done. Showing your difficulties with a code example will help you get specific and useful answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll do that and update the question.

Comment: @Jerome Note: by "compare" I meant either use unification with `=/2` or comparison with `==/2`. You will get different results if you have free variables.

Comment: About dicts working. Partially filled lists work: `T1 = [1, 2], T2 = [1, _], T1 = T2.` But partially filled dicts don't, I can't have a few properties set on a term, and try to unify it: `T1 = _{a:1, b:2}, T2 = _{a: 1}, T1 = T2.` doesn't work, I need unset properties to be considered free variables.

Comment: @Jerome Did you try `_{a:1, b:1} >:< _{a:1}`? I assume you did, this example is already in the answer by User9123.